# How to stop receiving Insider builds for Windows 10 without breaking VHD setup: \windows\systems32\winload.efi (0xc0000428)

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, windows-insider

I have enrolled myself into [Dev Channel of Windows Insider Program](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-insider/flighting). I am not quite sure whether I needed to enroll myself to Dev Channel of Windows Insider Program to setup my machine as a dual boot, but here is my dual boot setup:

1. Windows 10 (Version 10.0.21286.1000) [VHD] 
   -> Installed: Windows10_InsiderPreview_Client_x64_ja-jp_21286.iso
2. Windows 10 (Version 10.0.18363.1440)

I say I am not quite sure, because I believe I could have downloaded the ISO of Dev Channel build from [Windows Insider Preview Downloads](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsinsiderpreviewiso?lc=1033)'s Select edition without enrolling and probably installed it without a hitch.

Now I want to terminate receiving of Dev Channel's builds by following the instruction in [stop receiving Insider Preview builds](https://insider.windows.com/en-us/leave-program) on my main Windows 10 (Version 10.0.18363.1440). If I were to receive them, then it should be on the other one. When I stop it though, I get the following error message while booting my machine. Luckily I can load Windows 10 (Version 10.0.18363.1440), but the other one will result in an endless loop of the first and second screenshots. In order to get out of the endless loop, I loaded the Windows 10 (Version 10.0.18363.1440) and restarted receiving Dev Channel's future builds.

Preparing Automatic Repair:

[image]

The digital signature for this file couldn't be verified.:

[image]

Selection of Windows:

[image]

Loading of Windows 10 (Version 10.0.18363.1440:

[image]

Comment: Do you have two separate Windows 10 Licenses for the two installs?

Comment: @John, no. Although I can dual boot if I stay on to receive **Windows Insider's Preview**, it is not under agreed usage term: [Dual boot licensing, Win 10 x64 + Win 10 x64](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install-winpc/dual-boot-licensing-win-10-x64-win-10-x64/a54b3f46-b7ed-433c-afdf-be8c6515bf4d). Thanks for pointing it out to me. I guess I need to go & buy an extra license here: [Buy & Download Windows 10 - Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/b/windows?=en_US_Store_UH_software_Win&activetab=tab%3ashopwindows10)

Comment: **Personal Note:** Here is how to find out about one's acquired Windows' license: [License requirement for a Dual boot](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/0fee4e22-ee00-4680-9c16-1210a0a62d8d/license-requirement-for-a-dual-boot?forum=w7itproinstall). This link requires an Microsoft account to see.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you have two separate Windows 10 Licenses for the two installs? ...
> Answer: No

Two installations of the same Windows License (OEM or Retail) on the same computer may be allowed.  However my experience here is that I have had issues a while back when trying to run two systems simultaneously under one license.

**More importantly:**

You are also using Windows 10 V1903 (build 18363) and trying to use a version of Windows Insider that is not completely current.

> Now, I want to stop receiving Dev Channel's Insider Preview Builds on
> my main Windows 10 (Version 10.0.18363.1440).

In a stable situation (one installation) you can exit (quit) the program and your machine will return to Production at the first opportunity.

In this situation, Microsoft has said that to exit the Insider program and return to Production "right away" you must back up and reinstall Windows. Microsoft has also said that if Windows is not working, it may be necessary to reinstall.

Because your system is not working properly, I suggest you must do that here as well:  Back up everything, remove the dual boot, and install Windows fresh. Also come up to the current version.

Comment: The licensing wording is factually inaccurate due to how it was worded - Windows licenses are _per machine_, whether physical or virtual, not per OS image, and it doesn't violate the EULA to use one product key across 2+ OS images [ESD, VHD, WIM, 2nd `%SystemDrive%`] on the **same** machine; it would violate the EULA to use the image to boot a VM. This can be seen by capturing a WIM of their OS, applying the WIM to a separate partition, and booting to it - Windows 10 will still be licensed after running Windows Update [license check]; Boot it in a VM and the licensing would be auto-removed.

Comment: I changed the licensing part to make it clear this is my experience.  I have seen licensing issues when using the same license twice. I changed the re-installation need to focus on the system not working and Microsoft's expectation (Insider verbage) to re-install if broken.   Changes made - thank you.

Comment: There should never be a licensing issue when dual-booting the same OS image on Windows 10 when it's done on the same machine [whether physical or virtual], since the product key is tied to the motherboard's hardware ID and only one instance can be booted to at a time. A similar example of this was covered on [Spiceworks](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1110362-windows-10-and-mdt) _(look for the replies from the Microsoft vendor rep Chris)_

Comment: I made very significant changes in my answer to focus more on the error. At this point, if you cannot accept the new answer, please let us know.

Comment: I wasn't taking issue with your answer [I think it's a great answer], I only wanted to ensure the correct licensing information was disseminated, else misinformation tends to persist.

Answer (score 1):

> Now, I want to stop receiving Dev Channel's Insider Preview Builds on my main Windows 10 (Version 10.0.18363.1440). If I were to receive them, then it should be on the other one.

According to Microsoft, it is not possible to exit the Insider Preview program, if you selected and installed the Developer Channel Insider Preview build.  However, since you apparently have 1903 Insider Preview build installed, you should be able to exit the program by install 20H2 from a retail ISO.

The reason I am hopeful, that manually upgrading your installation to 20H2 will solve your problem is due to the fact I suspect you are not actually in the Developer Channel on the 18363 installation.  **You are likely stuck in the `Release Preview Channel`, in actuality, likely the `Release Preview ring` since you have a build from before it was changed.**

Since you are running 21286.1000 on the other installation, it's ineligible to receive any other build, since the Beta Channel hasn't caught up to it.  Since attempting to exit the Insider Preview program on the main installation, does cause an infinite reboot cycle (although how you got out of it is not clear), **there is a chance that the manual upgrade might cause the same problem.**

> But if you've installed a build in the Developer Channel because it's not tied to a specific release, you'll have to do a clean install of Windows and reset your Windows Insider settings on that device to switch.

[Switching between channels](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-insider/flighting#switching-between-channels)

Comment: Thank you for your input. Regarding your comment of `(although how you got out of it is not clear)`, I added a description to my original post regarding how I got out of the endless loop.